# How to get the sum of previous 10 rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Is it possible to get the sum of values in last 10 rows with respect to the current row?

I have created a database for a shop, which contains a table named purchase_details. Structure of that table is:

```
+--------------------------------+---------------+-----+
| Field                          | Type          | Key |
+--------------------------------+---------------+-----+
| Trans_ID                       | int(11)       | PRI |
| Dealer_Name                    | varchar(40)   |     |
| Todays_Purchase                | double(18,10) |     |
| Total_Purchase_In_Last_10_Days | double(18,10) |     |
+--------------------------------+---------------+-----+
```

Sample data:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| Trans_ID | Dealer_Name | Todays_Purchase | Total_Purchase_In_Last_10_Days |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
|        1 | Rahul       | 7769.1488285639 |                           NULL |
|        2 | Rahul       | 4158.5117578537 |                           NULL |
|        3 | Rahul       | 7200.1363099802 |                           NULL |
|        4 | Rahul       | 9338.8341269511 |                           NULL |
|        5 | Rahul       | 5897.7252866370 |                           NULL |
|        6 | Rahul       | 3266.6656585172 |                           NULL |
|        7 | Rahul       | 3188.0742696276 |                           NULL |
|        8 | Rahul       | 4270.5917314234 |                           NULL |
|        9 | Rahul       | 2604.3369713541 |                           NULL |
|       10 | Rahul       | 7908.6014441989 |                           NULL |
|       11 | Rahul       | 2693.4584823737 |                           NULL |
|       12 | Rahul       | 7945.7825034862 |                           NULL |
|       13 | Rahul       | 1904.1472157570 |                           NULL |
|       14 | Rajesh      | 7093.0478540344 |                           NULL |
|       15 | Rajesh      | 3219.3736989638 |                           NULL |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
```

I want get the sum of purchases done in last 10 transactions, with the condition that there should be at least 10 transactions to sum up.

Expected output:

```
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
| Trans_ID | Dealer_Name | Todays_Purchase | Total_Purchase_In_Last_10_Days |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
|        1 | Rahul       | 7769.1488285639 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        2 | Rahul       | 4158.5117578537 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        3 | Rahul       | 7200.1363099802 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        4 | Rahul       | 9338.8341269511 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        5 | Rahul       | 5897.7252866370 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        6 | Rahul       | 3266.6656585172 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        7 | Rahul       | 3188.0742696276 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        8 | Rahul       | 4270.5917314234 |                   0.0000000000 |
|        9 | Rahul       | 2604.3369713541 |                   0.0000000000 |
|       10 | Rahul       | 7908.6014441989 |               55602.6263900000 |
|       11 | Rahul       | 2693.4584823737 |               50526.9360400000 |
|       12 | Rahul       | 7945.7825034862 |               54314.2067800000 |
|       13 | Rahul       | 1904.1472157570 |               49018.2176900000 |
|       14 | Rajesh      | 7093.0478540344 |                   0.0000000000 |
|       15 | Rajesh      | 3219.3736989638 |                   0.0000000000 |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------------------+
```

For this, I've created a mysql function, which will take the Trans_ID and Dealer_Name as a parameter, and will return the sum of Todays_Purchase column.

Function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_TOTAL_PURCHASE(paramTransID INT, paramDealerName VARCHAR(40))
         RETURNS DOUBLE(18,10)
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalPurchase DOUBLE(18,10);
    SET totalPurchase = 0;
    SELECT SUM(Todays_Purchase)
        INTO totalPurchase
        FROM purchase_details
        WHERE Trans_ID > (paramTransID-10)
          AND Trans_ID <= paramTransID
          AND Dealer_Name = paramDealerName;
    RETURN totalPurchase;
END
```

And the SQL query to update Total_Purchase_In_Last_10_Days column is:

```
UPDATE purchase_details
SET Total_Purchase_In_Last_10_Days = GET_TOTAL_PURCHASE(Trans_ID, Dealer_Name);
```

Above SQL works properly, but it takes too much time to execute. There are more than a million records in the table, so the query takes more than 5 minutes. Hoe to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Derived information (such as what you are asking for) is properly done in `SELECTs`, not by having redundant code in the table.

If one user pulls up his info, it will be reasonably cheap to compute the sum on the fly.  And you already have the `FUNCTION` to do that.

However, can you really trust `Trans_ID` to be consecutive, no gaps, etc?  Your nomenclature is inconsistent:  "_Last_10_Days" vs "previous 10 rows" versus "Trans_".  "10 days" can be tricky if there are gaps.  Etc.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your reply.
Yes, Trans_ID will always be consecutive. So, in above example, when I'm calculating the sum for row where Trans_ID = 12, I will need to sum the previous 10 rows, i.e. having Trans_ID between 3 to 12.

Comment: This should be a breeze in MariaDB 10.2's "windowing functions".